# How to play video in card with cursor hovering over and overlay on video

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I want to make a card in which when I hover the cursor the video plays and there is an overlay on that video as well. I tried this but neither it is toggled or if I remove the overlay it works properly. But I want an overlay on the video which I am unable to do. So, can anyone help me to overcome this issue?

For this I used HTML, CSS and Javascript

NOTE- I have put all html code inside the anchor tag because when user click it, it will redirect to the another page.

```js
const clip = document.querySelectorAll('.clip');

    for (let i = 0; i < clip.length; i++) {
        clip[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
            clip[i].play()
        })

        clip[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
            clip[i].pause()
        })
    }
```

```css
.project {
        position: relative;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        filter: grayscale(1);
    }

    .project:hover {
        filter: grayscale(0);
    }

    .project video {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .project .project-name {
        color: #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10rem;
        left: 50px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 36px;
        line-height: 36px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 5;
    }
```

```html
<a href="" class="project">
        <video class="clip videoplay" preload="none" muted height="300px" width="500px" loop outline="none"
            poster="image.jpg">
            <source src="../videos/cl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support mp4 videos, change browser!
        </video>
        <div class="project-name">Sample Name</div>
        <!-- <div class="overlay"></div> -->
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery for play and pause in hover:

```
var video = $(".project").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```